# Issue in where condition while using in mdx

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I have parameter value: 'Paris carlton' when 'm trying to pass this value in mdx as (StrTomember(@Parameter)) i'm getting error.

How to pass the total name 'Paris Carlton' in where condtn. to filter the parameter value.

when i tried:when pass this parameter value, it is considering only Paris and not Carlton thus resulting in error. how to consider the full name while passing a value in mdx?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: when i tried to pass this parameter value, it is considering only Paris and not Carlton thus resulting in error. how to consider the full name while passing a value in mdx?

Comment: Than please [edit] your question so everyone can understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this :

```
(StrTomember(@Parameter))
```

Then @Parameter will need to be a string that represents the full member name. So you can either do an expression in `SSRS` to create a string that looks like this:

```
"[Geo Dimension].[Country hierarchy].&[Paris Carlton]"
```

Or you could build it inside the strToMember function:

```
 (StrTomember("[Geo Dimension].[Country hierarchy].&[" + @Parameter +"]"))
```